What does an empty @Injectable() decorator actually mean in Angular?
I'm not regular with Angular development. One thing I learnt about the @Injectable() decorator is that it means -

this class can have/take injected dependencies

and not

this class can be injected as a dependency

I cannot refer to any specific source right away (bad memory, getting old), but it was from articles online and may be some tutorials. I'm talking about an empty @Injectable() by the way, not about one with the providedIn property.
Anyway, looks like the Angular docs' narrative is aligned to reflect the later meaning. Here it says that the purpose of the decorator is

to show that the class can be injected.

and also here that -

The @Injectable() decorator specifies that Angular can use this class in the DI system.

So:

What exactly does an empty @Injectable() decorator actually indicate?
If the meaning of the @Injectable() is "this class can be injected as a dependency", then how come I can use a service class without the @Injectable() decorator as a dependency and it still works fine?


technically empty @Injectable() decorator marks the class to be processed with angular compiler. it analyzes parameters in the constructor and creates correct factory for that. for example class:
// no @Injectable()
class MyService {
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {}
}

can not be provided in providers array in a simple way providers: [MyService], as angular  doesn't know what to provide in the constructor.
apart from constructor injection, it doesn't really do anything.  Ir just tells developers that this class should be used in DI


What exactly does an empty @Injectable() decorator actually indicate?

That the class is a dependency that can be injected, but note that without providedIn property the service must be added to the providers array for it to be visible for dependency injection!

If the meaning of the @Injectable() is "this class can be injected as a dependency", then how come I can use a service class without the @Injectable() decorator as a dependency and it still works fine?

I would like to see this happen, you can only use the class as const someClass = new SomeClass() or you can create static methods and access them like SomeClass.someMethod where method will be defined as static someMethod() {...}, so there is no way a class can be used in dependency injection, because @Injectable() instructs angular framework that the class is a service, same goes for @Component or @Directive, this is how you register angular components and use them, else they are javascript class and nothing more!
The difference between a plain JS class and angular services is that
When you create a class like const someClass = new SomeClass() it creates a new instance, so the instance will have it own set of properties and methods, these are not visible to other instances.
When you declare a service in DI, the singleton will be shared to the current element/module, that has the service in the providers array and to all the children, the same instance is shared. ProvidedIn means, the single instance is used across the entire application!

Create a plain service class with export class SomeService{ } without the @Injectable() decorator, then add it as a Ctor parameter of some component. Doesn't it work for you?! Of course you have to add it the providers array of the module/component.

@atiyar technically you are messing with the internals of angular and probably doing the same thing as injectable, not sure if it's recommended to do like this though
